# how to know a div generated by which php file?

Tags: php, html, joomla

i'm using Joomla. I've installed a module that show latest real estates added. it have a button-set div showing a button with "Read more" on it. i want to change "Read more" to "Go to House". i do it in a file called default.php in lines below:

```
<div id="buttonest">
    <a class="readon" href="<?php echo sefRelToAbs( $link1 ); ?>" target="_self">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Go to House" /></a>
</div>
```

but when the page reloads it shows "Read more" button regardless of changes in this file. how can i know if this div is generated by default.php file or another file?
generally is there any way to know a div is generated by which php file? like monitoring page load o etc.?
p.s. : i have root access to host.

Comment: What does `echo sefRelToAbs( $link1 );` produce? PHP is executed on the page it's written on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe that particular file is overwritten, probably in your template folder.

Try to look in

```
/templates/{name of template you are using}/html/{name of component that you found the first default.php file}/{path to default.php similar to the first default.php file you edited}
```

Comment: yes, thank you, the file was being overwritten by another file in template folder with the same name. it solved by search and finding that file. it was not in components folder, it was is in template folder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the language files (in case that model has one)? If it sticks to guidelines, it should use a language string (to be found in /languages/yourlanguage/mod_modulename.ini or similar). You could also take a look into the Joomla language manager (overrides section) - search for "read more" or "read_more".

In both cases, you could just try changing the values.

Comment: That's the correct answer if the module developer is following Joomla practices and is separating the strings in language files.

Comment: thank you, your answer is correct and searching in language files is the first solution, i tried it, but in this case the php file was being overwritten by another file with the same name but in template folder. it solved by finding that file. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a value through the URL. On the PHP file, you can do :

```
<div id="buttonest">
    <a class="readon" href="<?php echo sefRelToAbs($link1)."?ref=default"; ?>" target="_self">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Go to House" /></a>
</div>
```

Then, anywhere in between PHP tags, you can :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ref']) && $_GET['ref'] == "default"){
  // you get here from the default page
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set an attribute on the actual div like

```
<div srcscript="<?php echo __FILE__?>">
```

But I'd remove them all before I went to production, maybe wrap them in an if debug==true condition or something.

To answer the actual question, no there is no default way to tell which parts of the output were generated by which included scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to directly identify which file is the source of a generated div.

What you could do however is do a search for a discriminating element in the content of all the php files, in that case "Read more" or more relevant.
From the root directory or subdirectory if you can narrow down `grep -nR "Read more" *`

Then you would have the whole list of the potential matching php files.

From this list, check them out one by one, or filtering more your search.

If multiple potential matches, add a temporary trace/log of some sort that would identify the file for you, using different texts or the constant `__FILE__` that would directly give you the name of the file.

Also, try clearing the cache as well before, it might just be related to it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time when editing Drupal or WordPress themes.  You want to "find in files" in your IDE or command-line and search for the identifiable information associated with the outputted markup in question.